# Open another instance of Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access

I am using a form in Access to open other access databases that perform various different queries that publish reports. As the databases I am opening use a multitude of tables, queries, and reports that have nothing to do with each other it would be awkward and time consuming to link to them all and tedious to make changes inside the original database.

I am using `Dim appAccess As Access.Application` to open each one.  It creates a 2nd instance of the new accdb which will not become visible.  However, if I go into view code in the original database and then go back to the form it opens the new instance perfectly visible and will continue to do so as long as I keep the original database open. If I close the original database and reopen it I have the same issue which can only be resolved by viewing the code again.
As an example of what I am using

```
Option Compare Database

Dim APP As Access.Application

Sub TEST()

Set APP = New Access.Application

APP.Visible = True

APP.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Documents\Database1.accdb"

End Sub
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I am not sure if this question was answered

Answer (score 0):

Add line:

`APP.UserControl = True`

For more info review [https://www.devhut.net/2018/01/21/ms-access-VBA-open-another-database/#:~:text=MS%20Access%20VBA%20%E2%80%93%20Open%20Another%20Database%201,to%20truly%20appreciate%20the%20power%20of%20automation.%20](https://www.devhut.net/2018/01/21/ms-access-VBA-open-another-database/#:%7E:text=MS%20Access%20VBA%20%E2%80%93%20Open%20Another%20Database%201,to%20truly%20appreciate%20the%20power%20of%20automation.%20)

Comment: adding line app..UserControl = true does not work

Comment: Since it did for me, can't explain why not for you.

Comment: well thanks for the help anyway. This occurs on two different computers using access 360 on a windows 7 and a windows 10 platform. Its driving me crazy.

Comment: That info is not in question even though it does appear relevant to issue. This code works on other computers? Appears you are not the only one encountering issue of code not work on those computer configurations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778422/front-end-multiple-users-with-different-access-and-windows-versions

Comment: It is not an issue of not working.  It does work after I view the code and then close view code. And continues to work every time until I close the accdb. The issue is why viewing the code impacts  the success of the procedure.

Comment: Since I cannot replicate issue, cannot offer solution.