# Front end, multiple users with different Access and Windows versions

Tags: ms-access, compatibility, multiple-users

I have an access application developed on Windows 10 - Office 365. The application is split in a BackEnd database shared between different users. FrontEnds are on user's computers.

For some users all works fine. No problems are encoutered, but for two users (one on Windows 7 / Office 365 and the other Windows 10 Office 365 (!)) the application blocks when specific data entry forms are opened giving error 2105 (Can't go to record). For instance:

```
Private Sub btnAddPsnCmp_Click()
Dim success As Boolean

On Error GoTo err_handle
success = validateData
If success Then
    Dim pId As String
    pId = Me.IDPerson
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPersonsXCompanies"
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmPersonsXCompanies", acNewRec
    ' DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Form_frmPersonsXCompanies.IDPerson = pId
    Form_frmPersonsXCompanies.personCombo.Enabled = False
    Form_frmPersonsXCompanies.cmpnyCombo.Enabled = True
End If
```

I replaced `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec` with `DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmPersonsXCompanies", acNewRec` directly from their pc, recompiled the code and it works. In other cases I had to change the DataEntry property of some forms to YES to make it work.

Is there no easier way to do this? How should I manage this with future versions of the application? On my computer I have no error at all so it is hard to imagine what problems will occur on other computers.

I double checked permissions on back end and on front end folder. Checked references are:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Access 16.0 Object library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database engine object library

I tried adding

- Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3

but it didn't change the issue.

Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: Everyone should be able to run the revised version of code so publish frontend with that. As for the DataEntry setting, no idea why that makes a difference.

Comment: I have made the experience that it is absolutely helpful to always only deploy **decompiled** and compacted databases to the clients. Maybe that helps.

Comment: I tried to decomplile, compact and recompile the (nonworking) code on their pc but didin't work

Comment: You  could try deployed a compiled front end as a accDE. See if that works better.

Comment: Appears you are not the only one encountering issue of code not work on those computer configurations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68773715/open-another-instance-of-access-using-vba/68776262?noredirect=1#comment121558266_68776262. I have no experience with Office365 but that seems to be the common denominator.

Comment: Thank you Albert D. Kallal. Took a step forward but not all solved yet!

Comment: I tried to save my file a accDE and got error, same if i tried to compact and repair my frontend: "The search key was not found in any record" so I followed Allen browne's advice on how to recover from corruption (http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html). I created a new database, linked my backend, imported my queries, modules and forms and recompiled. IT WORKS and I have a accDE file BUT it still blocks on the user's computer opening a specific form while on mine it works just fine.

Comment: If I change the dataEntry property ON THE USER's computer (accdb file) and save it (I compiled as well), it works. If I do it on mine, transfer it on his (accdb or accde) it blocks without even an error message (I do have error handling in my code) ?